# Centering text added by "content" CSS property in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, pseudo-element

I created an HTML table with some content. Some of the cells should have an asterisk (`*`) below its content, so I added an `asterisk` class to these cells:

```
<table class="numbers">
    <tr>
        <td class="asterisk">1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td class="asterisk">6</td>
        <td class="asterisk">7</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then, I added the following CSS rule, which uses the `:after` pseudo-element as well as the `content` property. It appends the asterisk and put it below the cell content:

```
.asterisk:after {
    display:block;
    content: '*';
}
```

Also, I added some room to the cells, put a border on them and, more importantly, made their texts centralized:

```
.numbers td {
    width: 40px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

With some more CSS rules (which can be seen in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brandizzi/kHJVN/)) I got the following result:

[image: Content added after cell is displayed aligned]

Well, I mean, I got this result on Firefox and Chrome, but I need it in Internet Explorer 8, too! There, however, I got this:

[image: Content added after cell is left aligned]

How could I get the first result in IE8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that, unlike other browsers, CSS-appended content from pseudo-elements in Internet Explorer 8 and below does not inherit the `text-align` property from the parent element. The solution is fortunately simple: just add a `text-align` property to the pseudo-element rule, as in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brandizzi/kHJVN/1/):

```
.asterisk:after {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    content: '*';
}
```

Or, better yet, you can make the child pseudo-element inherit the parent `text-align` property:

```
.asterisk:after {
    text-align: inherit;
    display: block;
    content: '*';
}
```

Comment: The solution is correct, but the explanation is not. IE8 is still treating the pseudo-element as inside, but it just isn't inheriting the text-align property. So it can alternatively be fixed by using `.asterisk:after { text-align:inherit }`